# MacBook Pro does not connect to WiFi network automatically

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, osx-lion, sleep, macbook-pro

At some point, my MacBook Pro (3,1, Late 2007, running Lion) stopped connecting automatically to my WiFi network, e.g. when awaking from sleep. Also, it takes it unusually long (~ 1 minute) from waking until a list of WiFi networks is available.

When selecting the WiFi network manually from the list, it connects without any further prompts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the problem. Lately I've changed my WiFi network's security from WEP to WPA2. In `Network Preferences | Advanced | Preferred Networks`, my network's name was still figuring with "WEP" under Security. That's why it wasn't connecting automatically.

Removing the network from the `Preferred Networks` list, disconnecting and reconnecting (so that my network would be re-added to Preferred Networks, this time with "WPA2" security) solved the problem.

BTW, I kept using the same passphrase for WPA2 as for WEP, so the information in the Keychain remained valid, and that's why manually connecting worked without prompts. Apparently in the keychain, the passphrase is only tied to the network name (SSID), while preferred networks are tied to both SSID and security type.

Comment: Yeah, I've had a similar problem before and it seems the only solution is to remove the remembered network and add it back again.

Comment: @Ilya Don't forget to accept this answer when you can (should be possible in a couple of days).